# Installed ubuntu over windows vista..cant reinstall windows

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery, ext4, windows-vista

I recently used the "compress hard drive" option within windows. i got the horid "boot mngr is compressed" after the restart. i tried booting my system back to windows vista but it doesnt read the cd that came with my computer. i tried going into system recovery and going back to a previous date but it didnt work. i kept pressing f8 but nothing. i installed ubuntu(the ubuntu cd worked but windows didnt?) i installed ubuntu so i could atleast get in my computer, and i still wasnt able to install windows from there. my hard drive got reformatted to a ext4? and windows cant install because it doesnt read it? im not sure, but its very frustrating. my computer is a gateway gt5668e windows vista home premium with sp1. im a graphic designer and use programs such as photoshop and cinema 4d to do my projects..i have been at a unfortunate halt with my work and i am really bummed out and dont know what to do... any help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows problem, not an Ubuntu problem. You would have better luck asking this question in a Windows forum - people are likely to have more specific knowledge.

Having said that, bootmgr is a file on the root of your Windows drive that helps Windows to boot. The error you're getting means that when you used the "compress hard drive" option in Windows, you managed to compress the bootmgr file too. Unfortunately, this breaks Windows.

The solution is to uncompress the bootmgr file. This is not easily done through linux. If you've managed to format your entire drive to ext4, then you've lost everything anyhow.

Comment: Absolutely right.  Marcuz, you might want to look into asking questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or another, more relevant, site.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the point made by YodaDaCoda is perfectly valid - I can make one suggestion:

Windows Vista (and its installer) cannot read the Ubuntu file system, but what it can do is format (wipe) the entire drive. Whilst I don't have a copy of a Windows Vista installer to work from, I am 100% confident that the options to formate the entire drive will be there somewhere. It may be called **create new partition table**, which will essentially do the same thing.

Once you've formatted the drive/created a new partition table, you will be able to create an NTFS partition for Windows.

Comment: i tried to format the drive but i only have one hard drive and it said that the drive needed to be unmounted for me to do that. and i cant unmount it because its the primary and only one that i have

Comment: I meant you should do this from the Windows installer itself, which will not have an issue with wiping the entire drive.